# Pylab colormap generator returns constant lookup table

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have the following `data['coeff']` column inside the `data` array:

```
[2.57270343, 3.65648059, 2.23084319, 4.80688107, 6.701842, 9.74599594, 7.05068671, 4.01677958, 3.37391547, 3.1511914, 2.38645804, 2.8914971, 3.49830092, 1.44652964, 6.689542, 7.57978187, 10.44210292, 9.96295341, 4.64736146, 3.1432992, 3.57139011, 3.46039262, 3.1436559, 2.56808725, 6.4063686, 7.31260831, 7.26623531, 10.46764653, 6.73590746, 2.7361601, 4.84963666, 5.61582771, 2.86951066, 3.46070112, 5.6345987, 15.91982055, 16.49156807, 11.90533765, 5.11663041, 2.0236397, 9.56519465, 7.69136698, 6.05681034, 4.23944285, 11.4375905, 23.21954318, 25.07053804, 14.68918469, 3.85383511, 2.2003411, 5.09153196, 6.61014214, 10.88575876, 5.09483765, 18.3454972, 27.26258116, 25.72212513, 8.84484278, 1.57545174, 1.8912232, 16.78862314, 20.29314535, 12.44983752, 3.6037403, 3.0240955, 2.30155483, 1.89219047, 5.04316851, 5.45651532, 5.4099686, 6.20357723, 3.29846311, 1.83343417, 5.46524273, 5.9786796, 4.16043566, 5.28458388, 3.69230367, 1.12351996, 3.5924855, 2.18969866, 6.26344489, 6.56806219, 4.03959973]
```

When I pass these data to `pylab.cm.RdBu(data['coeff'])` function it gives me back a constant table (each point has the same color):

```
array([[ 0.01960784,  0.18823529,  0.38039216,  1.        ],
       [ 0.01960784,  0.18823529,  0.38039216,  1.        ],
       [ 0.01960784,  0.18823529,  0.38039216,  1.        ],
       ...
       [ 0.01960784,  0.18823529,  0.38039216,  1.        ]])
```

It seems that something went wrong because when I use `scatter` with `cmap` everything works correctly (i.e. points are colored and scaled properly):

```
plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], c=data['coeff'], cmap='RdBu', marker='o')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib colormaps are normalized between 0 and 1. Any value `0 <= x <= 1` will give a color from the colormap. If you apply the colormap to a value `x < 0`, it will return the value corresponding to `0` and if you apply the colormap to a value `x > 1`, it will return the value corresponding to `1`.
The latter case is happening here. Since all values from the list are above 1, you will essentiall get the same result as

```
plt.cm.RdBu(np.ones(len(data)))
```

Most plotting commands that take a colormap as input will use a normalization internally to map the values to the range `[0,1]` first, then apply the colormap. The normalization can also be given externally in those commands, e.g.

```
plt.scatter(..., c=data, cmap='RdBu', vmin=1.2, vmax=11.5)
```

or

```
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=1.2, vmax=11.5)
plt.scatter(..., c=data, cmap='RdBu', norm=norm)
```

Applying a colormap to data directly would hence also require you to use a normalization.

```
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())
plt.cm.RdBu(norm(data))
```